# How detect collision two vector [svg] closed shape in C?

Tags: c, svg

1. Is possible to detect collision two or more closed shapes in C?
   I have char glyps (lines and(or) bezier path)
   [image: collision]

[image]

2. Is possible to detect distance 2 shapes? minimal distance between shapes.
   [image: distance]

Comment: Please make your questions more concrete, provide what you did so far to solve your problem and a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: _"Distance between 2 shapes"_ Distance from center of the shapes? Distance from center of mass between shapes? Distance between closest vertices of shapes? There are a lot of ways to define "distance between 2 shapes". All of them have different answers. You'll need to clarify what you're asking in order to get any meaningful answers.

Comment: ...or even shortest distance from a vertex to an edge. Or, for each vertex of one shape, determine which side of each edge vector of the other shape it lies. If it lies "inside" all of them, you have a collision. Then same vice-versa.

Comment: my images are very clear. I'm looking example, tutorial, library etc.

Comment: Your images do not have any "holes" as you have stated under an answer.

Comment: Better to post relevant data here than simple link to them - links can rot.

Comment: ok, i have to small reputation to put more images

Comment: @chux feel free and change my question.

Comment: please vote + , I add images and question is clear

Comment: What is your attempt to solve this? Voting to close because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "

Comment: answer is a library in C in title i wrote 'in C' tag "C"

Comment: Oops sorry the method in my first comment only applies to convex polygons.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to do non-convex collision detection.  Most collision detection algorithms work on two convex shapes.

One simple but inefficient way to do it is to break each of the polygons up into convex polygons and separately test each convex polygon against another in the opposite.  For instance, your "A" figure can be divided up into 3 convex polygons, and the seven-pointed star can be broken up into 8.  If any of the 24 possible collisions occurs, then the two original polygons intersect.

Another approach is to use conservative bounding regions as a first approximation.  Determine the two minimal circles that surround all points in the "A" and the seven-pointed star.  It is easy to determine circle collisions:  calculate the distance between centers and see how that compares with the sum of the circles radii.  If the circles do not intersect, then the polygons definitely do no intersect.  If the circles do intersect, then the polygons may intersect so further testing is required.

You can also combine these two approaches.  Before you test any convex subpolygons against each other, test the bounding circles of the subpolygons.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about collision detection. If these shapes are convex and polygons, you can use the SAT collision detection method. You project each vertex on each normal and look for an overlap. If on any normal there is no overlap you can exit and say there is no collision. If not the smallest overlap is you distance and the direction is the normal.

Comment: I have a line or bezier line (svg path) but my shapes have holes. Can You put link? Library? example?

Comment: This will not work with shapes that have holes. Concave polygons are more complicated to deal with. It is pretty common to use an algorithm to split them up into convex polygons or even just triangles.